# How does hibernate 5 works with My Sql Views?

Tags: hibernate, view, persistence

Id column in MySql Views always start with 1. When using with Hibernate, session stores the view entity in its persistence context and provide the same data for different query on same entity as id recieved as same as available in persistence context.

Has anyone encountered this situation. Please provide the way to resolve the issue.

Comment: As of now what I have done is to use different session object for all the save and update commands in the service. For fetching the view entity from database, I open and new session and close it after the data is fetched. It prevents views to stay in persistence context and hence does not override the data in subsequent queries.

I don't think this should be the right approach for this issue. Any other correct approach would be appreciated.